# Images not displaying when using the Dist Zip in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I created a play framework application.
It's operational when I `run` and more precisely, the images are correctly displaying.
But when I go for a `dist` and run the `start` script from the dist folder, the images are no longer displaying.
More info :

1. Images are stored in `/public/images`
2. My route assets :

`GET  /assets/*file                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

One curious thing is that I can access to the images via the URL from the routes (`/assets/name.png`) in my adress bar.

My images are shown thanks to `<img src="@routes.Assets.at("/images/name.png")>"`.

Hope you guys can help me find out this.
Thanks

Comment: Are the rest of your assets served correctly? Javascript and css? What is the rendered url of your images?

Comment: The rest of the assets seems to be displayed correctly.
The the url is `http://localhost:9000/assets/images/name.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, this :

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("/images/name.png")>"
```

has to be replaced with :

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/name.png")>"
```

Strangely, it did not break the dev mode of play "`run`", but did break the prod mode `dist`.